# For a given feature file - get list of all scenarios and for given scenario get list of all assertions

Tags: karate, gherkin

I have a task to programmatically retrieve all the scenarios for a given feature file. And for a specific scenario I need to get all assertions.

Is there a capability to do this in simple way? or have to go with pattern matching ?

Any help on this would be really helpful.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

This is internal to Karate and not officially supported. Perhaps pattern matching is the way to go, but it is up to you. You could look at Karate's code. Keep in mind that things like `Scenario Outline`s (especially the dynamic type) can get complicated.